# After upgrading to ml.net v0.10 Fit() ist not working

Tags: c#, ml.net

I'm using .NET-Framework 4.6.1

After upgrading ML.NET to v0.10 I cannot run my code. 
I build my pipeline and then I have an error when executing Fit()-Method.

Message = "Method not found: \"System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> System.Linq.Enumerable.Append(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1, !!0)\"."

using System.Collections.Generic; is in my directives.

Am I missing something or should I stick with v0.9 for now?

Thanks

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Core.Data;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;
using MulticlassClassification_Iris.DataStructures;

namespace MulticlassClassification_Iris
{
public static partial class Program
{
    private static string AppPath => Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);


    private static string TrainDataPath = @"..\machinelearning-samples\samples\csharp\getting-started\MulticlassClassification_Iris\IrisClassification\Data\iris-train.txt";
    private static string TestDataPath = @"..\machinelearning-samples\samples\csharp\getting-started\MulticlassClassification_Iris\IrisClassification\Data\iris-test.txt";


    private static string ModelPath = @"C:\Users\waldemar\Documents\model.txt";

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create MLContext to be shared across the model creation workflow objects 
        // Set a random seed for repeatable/deterministic results across multiple trainings.
        var mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);

        //1.
        BuildTrainEvaluateAndSaveModel(mlContext);

        //2.
        TestSomePredictions(mlContext);

        Console.WriteLine("=============== End of process, hit any key to finish ===============");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void BuildTrainEvaluateAndSaveModel(MLContext mlContext)
    {
        // STEP 1: Common data loading configuration
        var trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.ReadFromTextFile<IrisData>(TrainDataPath, hasHeader: true);
        var testDataView = mlContext.Data.ReadFromTextFile<IrisData>(TestDataPath, hasHeader: true);


        // STEP 2: Common data process configuration with pipeline data transformations
        var dataProcessPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "SepalLength",
                                                                               "SepalWidth",
                                                                               "PetalLength",
                                                                               "PetalWidth").AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext);

        // STEP 3: Set the training algorithm, then append the trainer to the pipeline  
        var trainer = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.StochasticDualCoordinateAscent(labelColumn: "Label", featureColumn: "Features");
        var trainingPipeline = dataProcessPipeline.Append(trainer);

        // STEP 4: Train the model fitting to the DataSet

        //Measure training time
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        Console.WriteLine("=============== Training the model ===============");
        ITransformer trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);

        //Stop measuring time
        watch.Stop();
        long elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine($"***** Training time: {elapsedMs/1000} seconds *****");


        // STEP 5: Evaluate the model and show accuracy stats
        Console.WriteLine("===== Evaluating Model's accuracy with Test data =====");
        var predictions = trainedModel.Transform(testDataView);
        var metrics = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Evaluate(predictions, "Label", "Score");

        Common.ConsoleHelper.PrintMultiClassClassificationMetrics(trainer.ToString(), metrics);

        // STEP 6: Save/persist the trained model to a .ZIP file
        using (var fs = new FileStream(ModelPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
            mlContext.Model.Save(trainedModel, fs);

        Console.WriteLine("The model is saved to {0}", ModelPath);
    }

    private static void TestSomePredictions(MLContext mlContext)
    {
        //Test Classification Predictions with some hard-coded samples 

        ITransformer trainedModel;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(ModelPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            trainedModel = mlContext.Model.Load(stream);
        }

        // Create prediction engine related to the loaded trained model
        var predEngine = trainedModel.CreatePredictionEngine<IrisData, IrisPrediction>(mlContext);

        //Score sample 1
        var resultprediction1 = predEngine.Predict(SampleIrisData.Iris1);

        Console.WriteLine($"Actual: setosa.     Predicted probability: setosa:      {resultprediction1.Score[0]:0.####}");
        Console.WriteLine($"                                           versicolor:  {resultprediction1.Score[1]:0.####}");
        Console.WriteLine($"                                           virginica:   {resultprediction1.Score[2]:0.####}");
        Console.WriteLine();

        //Score sample 2
        var resultprediction2 = predEngine.Predict(SampleIrisData.Iris2);

        Console.WriteLine($"Actual: setosa.     Predicted probability: setosa:      {resultprediction2.Score[0]:0.####}");
        Console.WriteLine($"                                           versicolor:  {resultprediction2.Score[1]:0.####}");
        Console.WriteLine($"                                           virginica:   {resultprediction2.Score[2]:0.####}");
        Console.WriteLine();

        //Score sample 3
        var resultprediction3 = predEngine.Predict(SampleIrisData.Iris3);

        Console.WriteLine($"Actual: setosa.     Predicted probability: setosa:      {resultprediction3.Score[0]:0.####}");
        Console.WriteLine($"                                           versicolor:  {resultprediction3.Score[1]:0.####}");
        Console.WriteLine($"                                           virginica:   {resultprediction3.Score[2]:0.####}");
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ML.NET v0.10 is working now. I had to update my .NET-Framework to 4.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

> - The API in ML.NET v0.10 and moving to 0.11, is being changed so it is consistent across many different classes in the API.

The issue you are facing might probably be caused because in many API methods **we changed the order of the parameters**. Hence, if those parameters are of the same type, it will compile but it won't work properly.

Check all your parameters being used in the ML.NET API so you make sure they are right.
Something that might help is to provide the name of the parameters, like:

```
.method(param1:value1, param2:value2)
```

Check this branch where we're migrating the samples to v0.10 if you're looking for additional help from the samples, ok?

[link](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/migration/v0.10)

Hope it helps. :)

Cesar

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out tomorrow.